# How to use/setup seiyria-bootstrap-slider?

Tags: bootstrap-slider

I confess I am newbie web developer. I just installed seiyria-bootstrap-slider with bower. I seem to have an issue get it to work. I have loaded the plug-in CSS and the JavaScript into my web page as per below basic instruction set.

Below is my index.html from which I use angular-route to navigate between different pages. I believe I am missing something. Also, below there is the slider element I defined. The element shows up in browser (Chrome) but its nobs are not movable.

Any clue is much appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

## Basic Setup

Load the plugin CSS and JavaScript into your web page, and everything should work!

Remember to load the plugin code after loading the Bootstrap CSS and JQuery.

**JQuery is optional and the plugin can operate with or without it.**

Look below to see an example of how to interact with the non-JQuery interface.

Still can't get it to work.

## The index.html

```
<html data-ng-app="eynakestanApp">
<head>

    <title>Eynakestan</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link href="/static/scripts/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/content/bootsnipp.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/static/content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
    <link href="/static/scripts/bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"  />


    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <!-- load angular via CDN -->
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold;">Eynakestan</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#product"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#userlist"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#compare"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span> Compare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#favorites"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Favorites</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#shoppingcart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Shopping Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#signup" ng-show="Username==''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign-Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#signin" ng-show="Username==''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign-in</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/" ng-show="Username!=''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Hi&nbsp;{{Username}}!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" ng-click="SignOut()" ng-show="Username!=''" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign-Out</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>



    <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
<div id="main">
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
</div>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/src/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## The Element

```
        Filter by price interval:<br>
        <b>€ 10</b>

        <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
            <div class="slider-track">
                <div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0; width: 19.697%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 19.697%; width: 52.0202%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0; width: 28.2828%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top" role="presentation" style="left: 45.7071%; margin-left: -33.5px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">205 : 720</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top" role="presentation" style="left: 19.697%; margin-left: 0; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">205</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-max top" role="presentation" style="left: 71.7172%; margin-left: 0; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">720</div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="10" aria-valuemax="1000" aria-valuenow="205" tabindex="0" style="left: 19.697%;"></div>
            <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="10" aria-valuemax="1000" aria-valuenow="720" tabindex="0" style="left: 71.7172%;"></div>
        </div>

        <input id="ex2"
               type="text"
               class="span2"
               value="205,720"
               data-slider-min="10"
               data-slider-max="1000"
               data-slider-step="5"
               data-slider-value="[250,450]"
               data-value="205,720" 
               style="display: none;"> 
        <b>€ 1000</b>
```

Comment: In general you should have a _minimal_ use case and set it up via jsfiddle. That will help isolate problems with your environment. That said, our repo has plenty of examples that should work for you. One thing that seems like it might help is using `data-provide="slider"` but I don't really want to read through all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't exactly pinpoint the issue. But, I fixed it based on the below self-contained example. I hope it helps others too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="../content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title></title>

    <script src="../scripts/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../scripts/bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../scripts/bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="myslider"
       type="text"
       class="span2"
       value="5,10"
       data-slider-id="myslider"
       data-slider-min="2" 
       data-slider-max="20"
       data-slider-step="2"
       data-slider-value="[5,10]"
       data-value="5,10" 

       />
<p id="slider"></p>


<script language="javascript">
    var mySlider = new Slider('#myslider');
    mySlider.on('slideStop', function(value) {
        document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = value;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Seiyria feel free to add comments, might I have missed anything.

Comment: Also, any chance I can get it to work with AngularJS controller variables?